# Intersection of two affine subspaces in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, affine-geometry

So I am havig an exam, and one of the examples last year was this:

IN vector space $R^3$, find intersection of two affine subspaces:

$$ (2,1,1,3,-3) + Span{(2,3,1,1,-1)}$$

and

$$N^T\cdot(x-p)=o\quad where \quad N=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & -1 & 0 & -1\\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \quad and\quad p=(1,1,2,1,2)$$

Now from what I know about affine spaces, I guess that in the first subspace (the one with span in it) the first round bracket is a point and the round bracket in span, is a translation vector.

However problem is with a second subspace, given by matrix equation, I can easily calculate ***x***, sice it is in fact ***p***, but that is just one round bracket, so is it suppose to be a point without  vector? And if yes, then there is another problem, because when I create this equation to find intersection:
$$(2,1,1,3,-1)\ +\alpha(2,3,1,1,-1)\ = \ (1,1,2,1,2)$$
it is overdetermined so it has no solution.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You are not making any mistake. The intersection is empty.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Thanks